# How to use "less -F" without "-X", but still display output if only one page?

Tags: git, less

I'm tweaking the pager of Git, but I've got some issues with it.

What I want is:

1. Always colored output
2. Scrolling by touchpad or mouse
3. Quit-if-one-screen

And my current configuration is:

```
$ git config --global core.pager
less -+F -+X -+S
```

This does everything except the last one.

But, if I remove `-+F`, there will be no output in case of one-screen. If I remove `-+X` as well, the output is back but I cannot scroll by touchpad in `less`.

Is there a workaround which can meet all the requirements above?

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  When I use `-F` (quit if one screen) I always do it in combination with `-X` (disable termcap init and de-init), but as you say, that wouldn't allow scrolling with the mouse.  (I doubt scrolling is possible at all with `-X`.)  I've modified the question title, but feel free to roll that back if you feel it loses too much meaning.  :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***UPDATE***

tl;dr Solution: upgrade to less 530

From http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.530.html:

> Don't output terminal init sequence if using -F and file fits on one screen.

So with this fix we don't even need to bother determining whether to use `-X` on our own, `less -F` just takes care of it.

PS. Some other less configs that I use:

```
export PAGER='less -F -S -R -M -i'
export MANPAGER='less -R -M -i +Gg'
git config --global core.pager 'less -F -S -R -i'
#alias less='less -F -S -R -M -i'
```

---

I eventually ended up with writing a wrapper on my own.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# BSD/OSX compatibility
[[ $(type -p gsed) ]] && SED=$(type -p gsed) || SED=$(type -p sed)
CONTEXT=$(expand <&0)
[[ ${#CONTEXT} -eq 0 ]] && exit 0
CONTEXT_NONCOLOR=$( $SED -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" <<< "$CONTEXT")
LINE_COUNT=$( (fold -w $(tput cols) | wc -l) <<< "$CONTEXT_NONCOLOR" )

[[ $LINE_COUNT -ge $(tput lines) ]] && less -+X -+S -R <<< "$CONTEXT" || echo "$CONTEXT"
```

BSD/OSX users should manually install `gnu-sed`. The amazing regexp, which helps remove color codes, is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000433/2487227

I've saved this script to `/usr/local/bin/pager` and then `git config --global core.pager /usr/local/bin/pager`

<s>The treatment for OCD patients, hooray!</s>

Comment: It won't work if your file has wrapped lines.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I deem that `fold` should handle that... but, yeah, bugs maybe... could you plz kindly provide an example?

Comment: @ThomasDickey https://paste.kde.org/ph9vl7es5 this one worked for me

Comment: `fold` doesn't really understand tabs.  You might be able to repair it using `expand`.  That still won't handle embedded escape sequences (which often is asked-for in the context of `git`).

Comment: @ThomasDickey grrrrr, it seems that there are quite a lot of cases to handle... could you give an example of "embedded escape sequences"? i haven't used that before...

Comment: @ThomasDickey i made a simple example of tabs in commit just now and it worked. what do you mean it doesn't "really" understand tabs?

Comment: tabs will only "work" when your terminal width happens to be a multiple of the tab-stops.  When I tested this, I noticed that `fold` did not adjust wrapped lines using spaces, but merely found the closest point for chopping.  So the appearance will be misleading.

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks for reply... and what about the escape sequence? Could you plz give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following wrapper as my pager.  It's not as fancy as the other wrapper shown here (because it always uses `less -S` to truncate long lines), but it's darn simple.  Seems to work pretty well with iTerm2.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

text=$(</dev/stdin)
text_lines=$(echo "${text}" | wc -l)
term_lines=$(tput lines)

if [[ $text_lines -lt $term_lines ]]; then
    echo "${text}"
else
    echo "${text}" | less -S -R
fi
```

Comment: You can also toggle back and forth between wrap vs. truncate in the middle of reading a file by typing -S <return> in less.